# Can I form a non-trivial loop from these vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that I am given $M>2$ (non-zero) vectors $v_i$ in $\rm I\!R^2$.  How can 
I tell if a non-negative linear combination of these vectors form a loop; i.e. is there a solution to $0 = \sum_i a_i v_i$ with $a_i>=0$ for all $i$ and $1=\sum_i a_i$?

Comment: Excuse me for being Mr. state the obvious here, but if the coefficients were allowed to be negative, you'd just have linear dependence as the defining characteristic. So your condition is something stronger than, but implying, linear dependence.

Comment: Conjecture: if there exists one vector with a negative $x$ and one with a positive $x$, and the same for $y$, then we can do this with at least three vectors.

Comment: @ColmBhandal that's my conjecture too, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Well, for a start, I would try an inelegant method: go through all the cases for the above condition in the conjecture. One case is that we have: (+, +), (-, -), (+, -). Another case (+, -), (+, -), (+, 0) ... and so on. $2^6 = 64$ cases altogether. Probably you can squash many cases into one based on symmetries e.g. symmetries between $x, y$ should halve that to $32$. But usually I find proving a specific case gives me ideas for the general case.

For each case just use algebra and see if you can choose the right coefficients.